# Html Country List with flags

Tags: javascript, html, country

I am looking for a way to select and display a list of countries, preferably with flags. Any suggestions?

I started of by trying this jQuery plugin http://www.graphicpush.com/website-language-dropdown-with-jquery, but as the list of countries I have is quite large it turned out that the performance was really bad (too many http requests to images). Also the list is bulky when it is larger than 50 elements.

Comment: did you google it? or try anything first? we are not going to do all the work for u :-p

Comment: See [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Maybe try downloading all the flags and use a batch image converter to reduce their size ?

Comment: Try populating a select element with the country names, and then displaying a small flag icon when the `onchange` event is triggered. You can also use a flag "sprite" (think many images in one) and manipulate the `background-position` instead.

Comment: I've looked into the sprite solution, but it would be a tedious job converting the ~80 images into a sprite..

Comment: There also appear to be some CSS sprite generators online. You might want to give those a try.

Comment: Here is a gist that use select2 plugin to populate a combo box with country and there flag https://gist.github.com/starx/eed701c8c84e0a475ce5

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Note from the future: jQuery UI autocomplete now supports custom
>   rendering by default, see
>   http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem.

It's pretty easy. Things you need:

1. [jQuery UI auto-complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
2. [UI auto-complete html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js)
3. A [list of country names/codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20100704023045/http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt)
4. A [CSS sprite with all flags](https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite)

Remember, Google is your friend. Blend the ingredients well, carefully whisk some javascript in, and it's done - in 7 lines of code:

```
var countries = [["Argentina", "ar"], ...];

var countryNames = countries.map(function(country){
  return {
      label: '<div class="flag '+country[1].toLowerCase()+'">'+country[0]+'</div>',
      value: country[0]
  }
});

$('#country').autocomplete({
  source: countryNames,
  html: true
});
```

[Here's this code in action](http://jsbin.com/upuve3/6)

Comment: Great! I didnt search for sprite with flags. Now I have all I need. Thanks a lot Ricardo!

Comment: I like this answer a lot, upvoted it but the jsbin is failing for me

Comment: fixed it for you :) it will probably break again in the future since it links directly to 3rd party sources.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi, the jsbin code does not show the flag accurately. For example the flag of Bangladesh is shown beside Belgium.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed this question is over 1.5 years old. As I said above, it's going to break because it's all built on top of third-party resources. This time it seems the sprite image has been changed (https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/tree/master/images).

Comment: UPDATED LINK to list of names / codes: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search

Comment: links #2 and  #3 are dead

Answer (score 37):

Just wanted to suggest a (imho) smarter way of doing the flags sprite.

The idea is to save the flags in a grid according to the country iso2 code.

1st letter -> vertical position
2nd letter -> horizontal position

Examples (for 16x11px flags + 4x4px spacing):

```
Austria = AT
A = 1   => vertically 1st row       => y = (1-1)*(11+4)  = 0
T = 20  => horizontally 20th column => x = (20-1)*(16+4) = 380

United States = US
U = 21  => vertically 21st row      => y = (21-1)*(11+4) = 300
S = 19  => horizontally 19th column => x = (19-1)*(16+4) = 360
```

This way I can calculate the flag location with a very easy function on the client side without the need of 200+ extra style definitions.

Sample jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    // size = flag size + spacing
    var default_size = {
        w: 20,
        h: 15
    };

    function calcPos(letter, size) {
        return -(letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 97) * size;
    }

    $.fn.setFlagPosition = function(iso, size) {
        size || (size = default_size);

        return $(this).css('background-position',
            [calcPos(iso[1], size.w), 'px ', calcPos(iso[0], size.h), 'px'].join(''));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo Usage:

```
$('.country i').setFlagPosition('es');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/TxAhb/

And here my flag sprite:

[image]

Comment: Elegant! Very elegant!! I wish I had this solution about a year ago :)

Comment: +1 for a very elegant solution.

Comment: This is a very neat solution

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by commenters, a CSS sprite is the proper solution here.  Fortunately, [there are many CSS sprites of flags freely available](https://www.google.com/search?q=country%20flag%20sprite&gws_rd=ssl).  [This one](https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite) looks pretty good.

We will have to tweak the dropdown code to accomodate that pre-made CSS sprite.  I've gone ahead and done that for you.  [Here's a live demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/jf5QK/)

**languageswitcher.js**

```
@@ -44,10 +44,11 @@
        source.removeAttr("autocomplete");
        var selected = source.find("option:selected");
        var options = $("option", source);
-       $("#country-select").append('<dl id="target" class="dropdown"></dl>')
-       $("#target").append('<dt class="' + selected.val() + '"><a href="#"><span class="flag"></span><em>' + selected.text() + '</em></a></dt>')
-       $("#target").append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>')
+        $("#country-select").append('<dl id="target" class="dropdown f16"></dl>')
+        $("#target").append('<dt><a href="#"><em class="flag ' + selected.val().toLowerCase() + '">' + selected.text() + '</em></a></dt>');
+        $("#target").append('<dd><ul></ul></dd>');
+        var $drop = $("#target dd ul");
        options.each(function(){
-           $("#target dd ul").append('<li class="' + $(this).val() + '"><a href="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"><span class="flag"></span><em>' + $(this).text() + '</em></a></li>');
+            $drop.append('<li><a href="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"><em class="flag ' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</em></a></li>');
            });
    }
```

**languageswitcher.css**

```
@@ -45,6 +45,8 @@

 .dropdown dd { position: relative; }

+.dropdown ul { max-height:350px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; }
+
 .dropdown a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
@@ -52,6 +54,7 @@
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
+    white-space:nowrap;
    }

 .dropdown dt a {
@@ -107,23 +110,6 @@
        padding: 2px 10px;
        }

-   .dropdown dd ul li a span,
-   .dropdown dt a span {
-       float: left;
-       width: 16px;
-       height: 11px;
-       margin: 2px 6px 0 0;
-       background-image: url(flags.png);
-       background-repeat: no-repeat;
-       cursor: pointer;
-       }
-
-       .us a span { background-position: 0 0 }
-       .uk a span { background-position: -16px 0 }
-       .fr a span { background-position: -32px 0 }
-       .de a span { background-position: -48px 0 }
-       .nl a span { background-position: -64px 0 }
-
    .dropdown dd ul li a em,
    .dropdown dt a em {
        font-style: normal;
@@ -138,3 +124,5 @@

        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1); }
        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover em { color: #fff; }
+
+.flag { padding-left:18px; }
```

The CSS changes I made were Q&D hacks; you'll probably want to spend some time polishing them.  I removed all of the flag-specific stuff from languageswitcher.css since we're using [flag16.css](https://web.archive.org/web/20110129202503/https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/raw/master/stylesheets/flags16.css).

Also, if the country code doesn't exist in the CSS sprite, the flag shown will default to the [image]
 African Union's flag since it is the first image in the sprite.  In the demo, several of the countries in my example list don't have a sprite image.  Watch out for that.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate solution! I was a bit intimidated at first by looking at the code here, but when I saw the live demo I saw that it wasn't as complicated as a thought. I went with the autocomplete solution this time. But I will keep this solution in mind for the future.

Thanks again Josh!

Comment: @Mr.B: The code as presented above is just a [udiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff), which makes it easy to see exactly what changes I made to the original code from your [link](http://www.graphicpush.com/demos/languageswitcher/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a file with the list of countries and links to their flags (some of the links might not be working though but most of them are)
[Excel File](http://www.2shared.com/document/qgON8S3o/Country_List__1_.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flags from http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/ and simply use CSS for positioning the appropriate flag.

----EDITED----

If i need to show flag of my country then i would do mapping from CSS like

`<span class='np'></span>`
`.np {`
`background: url(./flags_preview_large.png) -172px -397px no-repeat;`
`width: 14px;`
`height: 20px;`
`}`

Comment: It would be useful to add an example.

Comment: Ok i had added a clear example with html tag (span tag) that show map of Nepal with the help of CSS mapping which is all defined above.