# Select2 drop-down for countries, with flags

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Does somebody have an easy to use example of a country drop-down, with country flags, for `Select2`? I am about to implement one based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413008/647991) suggestion, but I would prefer to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 19):

I was working on a similar problem and here is how I solve it.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var isoCountries = [
            { id: 'AF', text: 'Afghanistan'},
            ...
        ];
        //Assuming you have a select element with name country
        // e.g. <select name="name"></select>

        $("[name='country']").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a country",
            data: isoCountries
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I also have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/starx/eed701c8c84e0a475ce5) about it and following are the demos.

- [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sgb4888k/1/)
- [Demo 2 with flags](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sgb4888k/2/) based on official [DOC](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) of `select2`

Comment: The [Select2; Examples - Templating](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) shows the flag when you choose a country as the selected option in the non-drop-down view. I've copied what they've done, similar to your [Demo 2 with flags](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sgb4888k/2/) however this does not show the flag upon chosing an option. How can I replicate this please?

Comment: Awesome solution - works for my Chrome page action extension

Comment: @TimMarshall If you still haven't fixed it, can I see some code with what you have attempted?

Comment: @GregTrevellick, Great. I am glad. Let me know once you finish your extension. I would like to see it.

Comment: @Starx, thank you for this solution, it helped me a lot. I know this answer is a bit old but I wanted to answer @Tim Marshall because I faced the same problem and the solution could help others. Firstly, you have to make sure to add the flag-icon CSS library (`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in 2019).

Comment: Secondly, if you want to see the flags on both the dropdown options and the selected option, you just have to add 2 lines: `templateSelection` for dropdown and `templateResult` for selected option. So you will end up with this: `$("[name='country']").select2({ placeholder: "Select a country", templateSelection: formatCountry, templateResult: formatCountry, data: isoCountries });`

Answer (score 6):

The way i did it:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" name="cdCountry" class="form-control" required />
</div>

<script>
    $("[name='cdCountry']").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a country",
        formatResult: function (country) {
            return $(
              "<span><i class=\"flag flag-" + country.id.toLowerCase() + "\"></i> " + country.text + "</span>"
            );;
        },
        data: yourDataSource
    });
</script>
```

and using the css library  (css and a sprite)
https://www.flag-sprites.com/

[Official DOC](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the following links.

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags
http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/country.html

Comment: second link is dead =[

Comment: first link is a good library but it has a lot of bugs and it is not responsive

Comment: @VivienPipo yes it is not responsive but it is very helpful and for responsiveness you need to make them responsive like change the width of .dd class

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="e1">
        <option value="1">Albania<img src="Albania.jpg"></option>
        ...
        <option value="2">Germany<img src="Germany.jpg"></option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is too raw. I still need to put together the images (jpgs, no way!), the list of countries, etc. I was looking for some javascript library where I can simply pass an array of countries (by ISO code, for example), and get a fully initialized `Select2` drop-down, with flags.