# Add an image to a drop down list (CSS/HTML) and mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am currently creating a drop down list that on click, it navigates to a different country's version of the website.

I want to add a flag to the left of the country name, but the inline styling won't work with a link.

```
<form id="country-select">
              <select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="">USA</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">CANADA</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">JAPAN</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">ITALY</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">FRANCE</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">SPAIN</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">GERMANY</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">CHINA</option>
                <option style="background-image:url('www.imagelink.png');" value="shop link">WORLD</option>
              </select>
            </form>
```

This code works perfectly on a PC, but doesn't work on mobile.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123117/4659987

Comment: @CenkYAGMUR Sorry, I would like them to appear always, not after clicking the dropdown arrow - thank you though!

Comment: i don't understand what do you want but maybe you can check it https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap

Comment: @CenkYAGMUR The drop down menus you gave me do not display a map at all times, only when opening the drop down menu it appears beside all countries. I want the map to show on the current selection and when selecting a country... Also my onclick navigation breaks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom dropdown. Either you can use [select2](https://select2.org) or [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) js libraray for the same. Go through their documentation how you can add flag(s).

Comment: I am updating a shopify layout, so I'm not sure (and also not very confident) to add this to a liquid layout - do you have any advice?