# how to span a color block along with text in options tag

Tags: html, css

Is it not just as easy as this?

```
<select>
<option>Red<span style="width:7px;height:7px;background:red"></span></option>
<option>Green<span style="width:7px;height:7px;background:green"></span> 
</option>
</select>
```

trying to acheive output like below

[image: colorDropdown]

anyone any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099370/select2-drop-down-for-countries-with-flags/33123117#33123117) Hope this help/guild you.

Comment: You can see this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select/7208814]

Comment: Im sorry but the above links did not help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use other `html` tags or `css` styling on select options. But you can use 3rd libraries to render dropdowns and use it like a select. For example `Bootstrap`

```js
$(function() {
   $('#my-select').find('li').click(function() {
      $('#selected').html($(this).html());
   });
});
```

```html
<head>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script class="cssdeck" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Single button -->
<div id='my-select' class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span id="selected">Colors</span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span style='width:10px; height:10px; background-color:red;display:inline-block;'></span> Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span style='width:10px; height:10px; background-color:blue;display:inline-block;'></span> Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span style='width:10px; height:10px; background-color:green;display:inline-block;'></span> Green</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: An extension to the question. im interested to know getting the same output using third party select2 library because it also has an option to search the options in dropdown [link](https://prnt.sc/jx36ts). Any ideas how to implement this with select2?

Comment: I have never used that library but I can see in the documentation there's a section for [custom dropdowns](https://select2.org/dropdown) and they use an example with flags. Try to replace the flags with your colors and It should work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not just as easy as this?

No it is not just that easy. Your browser would sanitize all the data inside options tag.

---

This would not be exactly what you are looking, but I prefer doing something like this:

```
<select>
  <option style="background:red;">Red</option>
  <option style="background:blue;">Blue</option>
  <option style="background:green;">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm exactly looking for the output like in the picture. I background color should not fill the complete area as per my requirement.

Comment: In the above method, if you say browser would sanitize . Any alternative JUST TO ACHEIVE OUTPUT LIKE IN PICTURE would also be fine for me. please suggest.