# Customize a select dropdown

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to customise a select drop-down.

Here is the final result.

[image]

Can I do it via a select dropdown?

Any help or examples links is really appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I had create the dropdown, however adding flags inside the dropdown is a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/yVDrV/ I'm thinking if it is possible with dropdown

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not make any attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This display exactly the image that I posted. However, I didn't use a drop-down.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="nav-country">
        <div id="top-country">
            <div id="left-top-c-container">
            <?php
                if ($_SESSION['australasia']==1) { ?>

                    <img id="auz-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/auz.png" alt="flag icon auztralasia">
                    <p>AUZ</p>                      
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/uk.png" alt="flag icon united kingdom">
                    <p>UK</p>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div id="right-top-c-container">
                <div id="right-arrow">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/arrow_dropdown.png" alt="small arrow image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-country">
            <?php
                if ($_SESSION['australasia']==1) { ?>   
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/uk.png" alt="flag icon united kingdom">
                    <p>UK</p>                               
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img id="auz-img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/auz.png" alt="flag icon auztralasia">
                    <p>AUZ</p>                              
            <?php } ?>      
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* COUNTRY FLAGS SELECTORS
 ================================================== */

#nav-country {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    right: 2%;
    top: 13px;
}


#top-country {
    width:84px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;  
}

#left-top-c-container {
    float: left;
    width:64px;
    height: 26px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#right-top-c-container {
    float: left;
    width:20px;
    height: 26px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;  
}

 #bottom-country {
    opacity: 0;
    width:84px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;  
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#bottom-country:hover, #bottom-country:focus {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

/*  Show the total country list  */
.visible {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}


#right-arrow img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Add the border to the arrow */
.rotate-on {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
}

/* Rotate the selected country drop-adown arrow */
.rotate-on img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);     /* Chrome and other webkit browsers */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);        /* FF */
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);          /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);         /* IE9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);             /* W3C complaint browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=-1, DX=0, DY=0, SizingMethod='auto expand');   /* IE8 and below */
}

#top-country p, #top-country img, #bottom-country p, #bottom-country img {
    float: left;
/*  margin-top: 6px; */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#left-top-c-container img, #bottom-country img{
/*  margin: 7px 8px 7px 10px; */
    margin: 7px 8px 7px 9px;
}

#top-country p, #bottom-country p {
    margin-top: 7px;
}

#top-country #right-arrow {
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

/* Add color text effect on the list of country */
#bottom-country:focus p, #bottom-country:hover p {
    color: #FFA217;
}

img#auz-img {
    margin: 7px 4px 7px 9px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#top-country").hover(function(){
                // Add class rotate-on to the 
                jQuery("#right-top-c-container").toggleClass("rotate-on");
                jQuery("#bottom-country").toggleClass("visible");
            });

//          Let the arrow pointing down when we are hovering the country list 
            jQuery("#bottom-country").hover(function(){
                jQuery("#right-top-c-container").toggleClass("rotate-on");

            });

            jQuery("#bottom-country").click(function(){
                //  We want to redirect to the correct url
                var country_value = jQuery("#bottom-country").children("p").text();
                if(country_value=="UK"){
                    var pathname = window.location.href;
//                  console.log(pathname);
                    pathname = pathname.replace('e.au.t','e.t');
                    pathname = pathname+"?selected_c=uk";
                    window.location.href = pathname;
                }
                else if (country_value=="AUZ") {
                    var pathname = window.location.href;
//                  console.log(pathname);
                    pathname = pathname.replace('e.t', 'e.au.t');
                    pathname = pathname+"?selected_c=au";
//                  console.log(pathname);
                    window.location.href = pathname;
                }
            });         
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure HTML and CSS is a [**little pain**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409780/html-country-list-with-flags).  However if you're interested in plugin you can use [**`select2`** with **Templating**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

It has flag along with names customized like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is using something other that a select element an option? If it is, you could replace it with a dropdown plugin, like the one that [Bootstrap offers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns). A component like this one will be far more easier to customize and style that a select. 
If you are planning to use it in a form or somewhere where the native capabilities of select may be needed, you can still use Bootstrap dropdown, adding on top something like this plugin that I developed: [Dropdown-select](http://jalba.github.io/dropdown-select/) 
Hope this helps.