# how to add country code list and their flags to html code

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to add country flag in html input tag and yeah bootstrap helper can do it. But i do not know how to add the links and scripts exactly that would solve my issue. So any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html Country List with flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409780/html-country-list-with-flags)